# Cell Level Security (or similar) in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, security

Does MongoDB support Cell Level security? I have found a few references claiming that it does (as of MongoDB 2.6), but I cannot find anything to verify this. I was hoping that if MongoDB did support this that I could find something in the documentation referencing this, but I have not.

If this is supported, do you use roles to handle this?

I do not even understand how "cell based security" really fits into the MongoDB model since documents are stored as JSON.

I am told that the application is essentially identical to the governments way of handling classified materials. I might have something "business sensitive" that only a person with an "employee role" role could access. I might also have project level roles, or even a manager for that project to limit what is seen.

Any help, pointers, or links are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB has field-level access via $redact. It isn't as secure as Accumulo's cell-level security because it isn't enforced by default. Read more here, https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/implement-field-level-redaction.